# Find $f(x)$ for $f(f(x))=\sin x$

Tags: functional-equations, function-and-relation-composition

Find all (if that's possible) functions $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $$f(f(x))=\sin x.$$

This is a problem a friend gave me. He said he saw it on a book a long time ago, but he couldn't remember what book. I literally have no idea how to solve this so I can't post my attempt here.

Comment: Do we require that $f$ should be continuous?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom No, I think.

Comment: **Thoughts:** First, find $\tilde f:[-\pi/2,\pi/2] \to \Bbb R$ such that $\tilde f(\tilde f(x)) = \sin(x)$.  Intuitively this should be possible, since on this interval $\sin(x)$ is a strictly increasing function.  From there, it suffices to define
$$
f(x) = \tilde f([x]_{\pi})
$$
where $[x]_\pi$ denotes the unique value in $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$ such that $x = 2\pi k + [x]_\pi$ **or** $x = 2\pi k + \pi - [x]_\pi$ for some $k \in \Bbb Z$.

Comment: With $f(f(x))=\sin x$ we get $f(\sin x)=\sin f(x)$. Are you sure that your question makes sense ? Is the question just for fun or have a purpose ?

Comment: The question was discussed in much detail in the math-overvlow thread http://mathoverflow.net/q/45608/7710 *(Perhaps we should mark this question as duplicate?)*

Comment: @Gottfried Helms : Thanks for the hint. It's duplicate, yes, but here are posted other answers.

Answer (score 3):

I think there is an analytic solution.

Let $f(z) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n z^n$ be analytic for $|z|$ small enough. We have
$$f(f(z)) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n f(z)^n =\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n (\sum_{k=1}^\infty c_k z^k)^n$$
$$ = \sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n \sum_{m=1}^\infty z^m \sum_{\sum_{l=1}^n k_l = m} \prod_{l=1}^n c_{k_l}$$
$$ = \sum_{m=1}^\infty z^m  \sum_{n=1}^m c_n\sum_{\sum_{l=1}^n k_l = m} \prod_{l=1}^n c_{k_l}$$
And if we are given an analytic function $g(z) = \sum_{m=1}^\infty b_m z^m$, the equation $g(z) = f(f(z))$ for $|z|$ small enough becomes

$$b_m = \sum_{n=1}^m c_n\sum_{\sum_{l=1}^n k_l = m} \prod_{l=1}^n c_{k_l}$$
$$ = c_1 c_m + c_m c_1^m + \underbrace{\sum_{n=2}^{m-1} c_n\sum_{\sum_{l=1}^n k_l = m}\prod_{l=1}^n c_{k_l}}_{\text{only } c_k, \  k < m \text{ appears there}} $$

so that a solution for the coefficients always exist when $b_1 = 1$ :
$$c_1 = 1, \qquad c_m = \frac{1}{2}(b_m - \sum_{n=2}^{m-1} c_n\sum_{\sum_{l=1}^n k_l = m}\prod_{l=1}^n c_{k_l})$$
**All we have to do then** is proving $f(z) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n z^n$ converges : that $c_n = \mathcal{O}(R^n)$ for some $R$.

Comment: I've picture for the growthrate of those coefficients. In the interval of the first 256 terms they show such a growth curve that it is extremely unlikely that the full powerseries might have a nonzero radius of convergence. See for instance this http://go.helms-net.de/math/images/sincoeff_c.png and for further analysis perhaps this http://go.helms-net.de/math/images/sincoeff_d.png

Comment: The most relevant answer for the question of radius of convergence being zero or not is perhaps http://mathoverflow.net/a/46791/7710

Comment: @GottfriedHelms tks, I see this is not so easy then :)  and as you said it is probably not analytic (as $h(z) = \frac{z}{1- R z}, h(h(z)) = \frac{z}{1-2Rz}$ indicates). I'll try to understand something of all your links and hints

Comment: You're welcome - don't hesitate to ask open questions; as far as I can I'll try to answer and possibly include in the above post.

Answer (score 3):

There are uncountably many solutions. Let $\sigma$ be any involution of $I_0=(1,\pi/2]$ without fixed points. For example, we could take
$$
  \sigma(x)=\begin{cases}
    ax+\frac{\pi/2-a^2}{a+1}&\text{if }1<a\leq\frac{a+\pi/2}{a+1},\\
    x/a+\frac{a-\pi/(2a)}{a+1}&\text{if }\frac{a+\pi/2}{a+1}<a\leq\pi/2
  \end{cases}
$$
for any $a>0$. Let $I_n=\sin(I_{n-1})$ for $n>1$. Note that
$$
  (0,\pi/2]=\bigsqcup_{n\geq 0}I_n.
$$
Now define $f$ according to the following rules:
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
  f(0)&=&0,\\
  f(x)&=&\sigma(x)\text{ if }x\in I_0\text{ and }x>\sigma(x),\\
  f(x)&=&\sin(\sigma(x))\text{ if }x\in I_0\text{ and }x<\sigma(x),\\
  f(x)&=&\sin(f(\sin^{-1}(x)))\text{ if }x\in I_n,\,n>0,\\
  f(x)&=&-f(-x)\text{ if }x\in[-\pi/2,0),\\
  f(x)&=&f(\pi-x)\text{ if }x\in(\pi/2,3\pi/2],\\
  f(x)&=&f(x-2\pi)\text{ if }x>3\pi/2,\\
  f(x)&=&f(x+2\pi)\text{ if }x<-\pi/2.
\end{eqnarray*}$$
Note that exactly one rule applies to each $x\in\mathbb R$. Also the rule for $x\in I_n$ implies $f(\sin x)=\sin f(x)$ for $x\in(0,\pi/2]$. We can verify $f(f(x))=\sin x$ by considering each possibility for $x$. If $x\in I_0$ and $x>\sigma(x)$ then $\sigma(\sigma(x))=x>\sigma(x)$, so
$$
  f(f(x))=f(\sigma(x))=\sin(\sigma(\sigma(x))=\sin x.
$$
If $x\in I_0$ and $x<\sigma(x)$ then
$$
  f(f(x))=f(\sin(\sigma(x))=\sin f(\sigma(x))=\sin x.
$$
If $x\in I_n$ and the statement holds on $I_{n-1}$ then
$$
  f(f(x))=f(\sin(f(\sin^{-1}(x))))=\sin(f(f(\sin^{-1}(x))))=\sin x.
$$
If $x\in[-\pi/2,0)$ then
$$
  f(f(x))=f(-f(-x))=-f(f(-x))=-\sin(-x)=\sin x.
$$
Thus $f(f(x))=x$ for $x\in[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$, and the remaining rules extend this to $x\in\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 3):

There have been a couple of questions about this function at MSE and Math Overflow, perhaps the best discussion related to your question is at [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/q/45608/7710) which includes a solution via the technique of finding the Abel-function introduced by J.Ecalle.

I've looked -more naively- at the formal power series up to the 512'th term finding strong divergence [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/45608/does-the-formal-power-series-solution-to-ffx-sin-x-converge/45767#45767) or [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/45657/7710) so concluding the radius of convergence of the power series being zero (but the series usable as asymptotic series giving usable approximations at truncations of the series, or being Noerlund-summable in the sense of summation-procedures for divergent series)

A picture of $y=\sin(x)$, the half-iterate $y=\sin^{\circ 0.5}(x)$ , $y=\sin^{\circ 1/3}(x)$ and $y=x$ (using the asymptotic powerseries of Ecalle's Abel-solution as shown in that thread at MO)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Now, given a specific $x$ with $x_1 = \sin x$ and $ x_{n+1} = \sin x_n$ it is a result of Jean Ecalle at Orsay that we may take
$$ \alpha(x) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \; \; \; \frac{3}{x_n^2}  \; + \; \frac{6 \log x_n}{5}  \; + \; \frac{79  x_n^2}{1050}   \; + \; \frac{29  x_n^4}{2625}  \; - \; n.$$

Note that $\alpha$ actually is defined on  $ 0 < x < \pi$ with
$\alpha(\pi - x) = \alpha(x),$ but the symmetry also means that the inverse function returns to the interval  $ 0 < x \leq \frac{\pi}{2}.$ You can see how this cannot be extended around the origin as a meromorphic function because of the evident logarithm term.

Before going on, the limit technique in the previous paragraph is given in pages 346-353 of *Iterative Functional Equations*
by Marek Kuczma, Bogdan Choczewski, and Roman Ger. The solution is specifically Theorem 8.5.8 of subsection 8.5D, bottom of page 351 to top of page 353. Subsection 8.5A, pages 346-347, about Julia's equation, is part of the development.

We define ( at least for $ 0 < x \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$) 
$$ f(x)  = \alpha^{-1} \left( \frac{1}{2} + \alpha(x)   \right) $$
That's the short version. In Milnor's book, $\alpha$ is called a Fatou coordinate.